# How to make CheckTextView stayed in its state in android?

Tags: java, android, android-checkedtextview

ChechTextView working, but when close app, and re-open app, they all unchecked again.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // change the checkbox state
                final CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView)view);
                //checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());

                if (checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    checkedTextView.setPaintFlags(checkedTextView.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                else {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);

                    checkedTextView.setPaintFlags(checkedTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The view does not store checked data after app finishes. You need to do this yourself

Answer (score -1):

```
 swSecuritySettings.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            if (isTouched) {
                isTouched = false;

                //do task
            }
        }
    });

    swSecuritySettings.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            isTouched = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```